# Why does uitabbaritem have so few available images?

Tags: ios, ios10

I am using uitabbaritem enumeration images:

```
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarsystemitem
```

But there seem to be so few of them. Is there some other type of item that I can use also in the tab bar or am I limited to just these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `init(title:image:selectedImage:)` to create a tab bar item in which you supply your own image.

Comment: Thanks Matt,  are there any good sites u could suggest as places for me to look for images that are the correct size and high quality?  Do they have to be png to be the best quality?

Comment: You could use SVG images, they suppose to scale well